# What are the pros and cons of a spy humanoid robot of these heights? which height will have the most advantages?

Tags: humanoid, robots, espionage

In my story, they have humanoid robots (humanoid for a reason in the story, but no need to write it here) living with humans, so one of the humanoid robots are designed for spying/information gathering/intelligence, working for governments to gather information and following/tracking people, they may need to escape without getting noticed or fight in rare cases (since it's rare u could ignore it).

**The heights that I'm talking about are:**

1. 150-180cm
2. 130-100cm
3. 90-80cm
4. 60-20cm

What are the pros and cons of these heights? which height will have the most advantages?

I don't know what other details should I write, feel free to write other conditions/reasons, since it's not limited to what I wrote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**150-200cm**

- Can blend in provided they're lifelike enough
- Longer limbs likely means faster escape speeds
- Can't hide much more than humans can

**90-150**

- If lifelike enough, can camouflage as a child. Children can be odd in their behavior, so easier to 'blend in' even if the movements aren't exactly right
- Considerably easier to hide
- No real downsides from the 150-200cm range, unless there's a need to pass as an adult.

**60-100**

- Too small again to pass as a child, no real benefit over the last range

**20-60**

- Ultimate size range for covert ops, provided your world and the locations are not white glass hallways with no dark corners
- If this is the size of the full, functioning memory core /processing units etc, then they could utilize a full sized humanoid body as a transportation vessel until caught, then ditch the clumsy body for their escape. Imagine androids just popping their head off and it rocketing into the sunset by itself at supersonic speeds.